# Extracting only a certain word from a string

Tags: regex, substring

I have list of US presidents with speeches about various topics (although some don't have labels) and in the column filename I have something in the format like

`1981_Reagan, 1982_economy_Reagan... 1994_Clinton, 1994_criminal_justice_Clinton`

(each in a separate row) and I'd like to extract which president spoke. I was going to use a function like `sub_str` but not sure how to go about extracting the just the name - obviously the different lengths of names are a consideration, but also not wanting to extract unwanted information such as the year or other words.

Comment: from the R - Tag info: `"R is a free, [...] computing. Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks. For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com."`

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple way using strsplit, assuming the president name is always at the end of the string separated from everything by "_":

```
vec <- c("1981_Reagan",
         "1982_economy_Reagan",
         "1994_Clinton",
         "1994_criminal_justice_Clinton")
sapply(strsplit(vec, "_"), function(x) x[length(x)])
#output
"Reagan"  "Reagan"  "Clinton" "Clinton"
```

basically split the strings by "_" and extract the last element from each resulting vector

Another way using regex:

```
sub(".+_", "", vec)
```

replace any characters up to `_` with nothing. This is greedy so it will replace until the last `_`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'd like to see as the output. Thanks

Comment: @The Statistician Magician glad to help, I added one more way with `gsub`

Comment: why don't you just do `sub(".+_", "", vec)`?

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks I added it just before you commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

```
vec <- c("1981_Reagan",
         "1982_economy_Reagan",
         "1994_Clinton",
         "1994_criminal_justice_Clinton")

sub(".*_(\\w+)","\\1",vec,perl=T)

#[1] "Reagan"  "Reagan"  "Clinton" "Clinton"
```

---

My solution seems to be the fastest by using Perl.

```
vec <- c("1981_Reagan",
         "1982_economy_Reagan",
         "1994_Clinton",
         "1994_criminal_justice_Clinton")

vec <- rep(vec,99999)

f1 <- function(vec) {sub(".*_", "", vec)}

f2 <- function(vec) {sub(".*_(\\w+)","\\1",vec,perl=T)}

f3 <- function(vec) {gsub(".+_", "", vec)}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark( f1(vec), f2(vec), f3(vec),times=100)

#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# f1(vec) 212.8052 213.9725 215.5334 215.1973 216.5564 222.4681   100  b 
# f2(vec) 133.7839 134.6375 136.0296 135.0752 136.3612 142.8160   100 a  
# f3(vec) 290.8456 293.4051 295.5549 294.5525 295.5341 338.8277   100   c
```

Comment: `sub(".*_", "", vec)` will do the work. No need to capture and use backreferencing which will slow down the program

Comment: have not seen that

Comment: @Onyambu last time I trusted you blindly ;-).

Comment: You change two variables in the comparison. perl and backreferencing.

Comment: How can you compare the two yet you used `PERL` in the second one and never used `perl` in the first one??? If you are using `perl` use `perl` for both of them or decide not to use `perl` for both of them and you will understand that `capturing` with back reference has higher complexity and thus more time

Comment: I have looked at the speeds of the solutions given.

Comment: and what did you find?

Comment: mine got an a :-)

Comment: but I see you guys point. If I remove the perl from my solution its not faster. Anymore. Trust restored ;-).

Comment: there is no way that can happen. you used `sub(".*_(\\w+)","\\1",vec)` and if you wanted to know the complexity then you could have compared with `sub(".*_", "", vec)` actually even `gsub(".*_", "", vec)` is faster than yours since you have backreferencing

Answer (score 0):

One regularity, at least, in the example input is that the presidents' names (**and only their names**) are capitalised.

You can capitalise on that...

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(original_string, "(?<=_)[A-Z][^_]+")
[1] "Reagan"  "Reagan"  "Clinton" "Clinton"
```

Where

```
original_string <- c(
  "1981_Reagan", 
  "1982_economy_Reagan", 
  "1994_Clinton", 
  "1994_criminal_justice_Clinton"
)
```

Comment: `original_string<-
"1940_World War II speech_Roosevelt"`

Comment: @AndreElrico yes, that's realistics - example input is very limited (and little description).  I added a caveat in bold to my answer.

Comment: just use the regex `(?<=_)[^_]+$`in that case you will take into consideration that you just need the last string. eg in base R: `regmatches(original_string,regexpr('(?<=_)[^_]+$',original_string,perl = T))`

Comment: @Onyambu, that the strings end with the name seems reasonable but two answers already build on that.. so my solution is an alternative in case you have something like: "2009_middle_east_Obama_cairo"